# Как добавить FOREIGN KEY к таблице?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE `wallets` (
        `idwallets` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         .............
        PRIMARY KEY (`idwallets`),
        UNIQUE INDEX `wallet_UNIQUE` (`wallet`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=114


CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `idorders` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_idorder` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ..............
    PRIMARY KEY (`idorders`),
    INDEX `fk_orders_wallets_idx` (`wallets_idwallets`),
    INDEX `order_idorder` (`order_idorder`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_wallets` FOREIGN KEY (`wallets_idwallets`)
      REFERENCES `wallets` (`idwallets`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=97


CREATE TABLE `order` (
    `idorder` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ..........
    PRIMARY KEY (`idorder`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Хочу добавить FOREIGN KEY в таблицу `orders` строку `idorder`
Добавляю вот так:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_order`
    FOREIGN KEY (`order_idorder`) REFERENCES `order` (`idorder`)
```

но, выпадает ошибка:

> AED8C8C1CAC0 SQL (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`exchange`.`#sql-242c_130`, CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_idorder`) REFERENCES `order` (`idorder`))

помогите разобраться, прочитал уже много инфы но что-то не получается

Comment: Возможно, некоторые значения не удовлетворяют FK? Не работал с mysql, просто предположение.

Comment: @soon ну так одна таблица связана таким же способом

Comment: Значит в той второй таблице все ok. А в orders похоже содержаться записи с order_idorder отсутствующими в order

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли такие значения полей, которые не подходят под ограничения FK: `SELECT orders.*
FROM orders LEFT JOIN order ON order.idorder=orders.order_idorder
WHERE order.idorder IS NULL`

Comment: @mike Спасибо, действительно в той таблице просто небыло никаких записей, добавил в нее записи, и в orders в поле order_idorder добавил значение из таблицы order все заработало! Блин тупил целый день, спасибо за помощь